# Show div depending on class on link

Tags: php

I am looping through some images of houses where all have a link to the house detail page.  But i have one image that is in the that has a different link where it is being linked to the staff page.

**Issue**

How do i get that one link to go to the Staff detail page. I have tried to show different blocks of code depending on what class is inserted from the CMS? any suggestions?

```
<?php

$page_link = team;

if ( $page_link == {@page} ) {

?>
<a href="/team" class="{@remove_link} {@page}" >
    <div class="project {@grey_scale} grid-item {@tile_size_width} {@tile_size_height}" style="background:url('{@image_1}{@video_image}');background-size: cover; background-position:center;">
    </div>
</a>
<?php

} else {

?>
<a href="{@guid}" class="{@remove_link} {@page}" >
    <div class="project {@grey_scale} grid-item {@tile_size_width} {@tile_size_height}" style="background:url('{@image_1}{@video_image}');background-size: cover; background-position:center;">
    </div>
</a>
<?php

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you dont need to duplicate the whole HTML. You could just set the `if` around the `<a>` like:

```
<?php

$page_link = "team";

if ( $page_link == {@page} ) { 

?>

<a href="/team" class="{@remove_link} {@page}" >

<?php } else { ?>

<a href="{@guid}" class="{@remove_link} {@page}" >

<?php } ?>
```

You need to know what is on `{@page}`. If it's "team", then you can do your `if` thing. If not, you have to adjust your `$page_link` to the same of your `{@page}` var.

If your team-page adress is something like `stansmith.com/pages/team`, then you have to change the `<a href="/team">` to `<a href="/pages/team">`.

Please tell me if you need more help.